# How can I get the Value of one of the add key fields (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get the Value of one of the add key nodes with an SQL statement.
Something like

```
SELECT ColXML from table where value = 'Tom'
```

I only want the row that has this value as the other rows contain the same XML but have different values.
The table is 
ID, colXML, Createtime the colXML column is a VARCHAR as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appSettings>
     <add key="1" Value="John">
     <add key="2" Value="Tom">
     <add key="3" Value="Eric">
     <add key="4" Value="Jane">
     <add key="5" Value="Sarra">
     <add key="6" Value="Suzie">
     <add key="7" Value="Rick">
     <add key="8" Value="Jim">
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you store XML in a column, its datatype should **really** be `XML` - not `varchar` ....

If you **do have** the column as `XML`, then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ColXml.exist('/appSettings/add[@Value="Tom"]') = 1
```

With this, you're basically checking to see if one entry `<add>` with a `Value="Tom"` attribute exists - and if so, you're selecting that row from the database table.

With your `varchar` column, you might need to use

```
WHERE CAST(ColXml AS XML).exist('/appSettings/add[@Value="Tom"]') = 1
```

in order to get an `XML` value so the XQuery `.exist()` method can be applied - but again: you should **really** convert that column to `XML` !